# How to make the desktop pane that Netbeans has

Tags: java, netbeans, panel, desktop

So when I start up Netbeans, they create a little panel on the desktop for showing the progress of loading. I'm pretty sure Microsoft Office 2010 uses this too. I was curious how to make one of those in java?
I looked through the API and saw JDesktopPane. But I don't think that's what I'm looking for unless you can take that and put in on the actual desktop, but I'm unsure. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can actually do it using JPanel.. you don't need to do anything else..no need of desktop pane
all you need to do is design a `JPanel` and put a progress bar inside it that will link to a process and show how much it has been completed.
JPanel doesn't have normal frame functionality like minimize, Close etc and will act exactly as you are trying to make up.

**Update :** Just tried doing what you wanted.
You need to start working on JFrame. and set its decoration to false.
in Netbeans, you can just go to Frame properties and set Undecorated to true
or inside code you can just write `setUndecorated(true);`

then you have to design your frame, put a progress bar inside it, link it to a function, set its onTop value to true (which means it will always be on top) and set its position to center of screen. done!! you are ready with your window!!